# fisher.test many files (already with table data) input

Tags: r, statistics

I want to do fisher.test in R.

I already have data for contingency tables (in separate file.txt).

I want to:

1. Input files & match them according their names;
2. Input matched file data for the test;

-All files looks like that:

```
 56
 989
```

All files have only two rows (#1 occurred & #2 non occurred);

-File names are:

```
Anna_50.txt
Anna_100.txt
Anna_200.txt
Ben_50.txt
Ben_100.txt
Ben_200.txt
```

-I want to do Fisher test for Anna_50 & Ben_50; Anna_100 & Ben_100 etc:

-Questions:

```
files <- list.files()
```

How to match Anna_50 and Ben_50 in files;

How to create matrix as order of input is tricky.

```
table <- matrix(c(Anna_50_Occ, Ben_50_Occ, Anna_50_NonOn, Ben_50_NonO)2,2)
```

How to run this over all the files?

Looking forward to your answers. Tried to make this as clear  as possible - I really  need this, but if there is something still unclear don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have some code that should do the trick. However, as I don't have your files, the last part may fail.

The idea is the following. First, you read the numbers from `files`. Then, you create two vectors containing the filenames. One for all Anna files, one for Ben files. Then you create a function for running a Fisher test on two of these objects. The final magic is achieved by `mapply` iterating simultaneously over the two vectors of filenames:

```
files <- c("Anna_50.txt", "Anna_100.txt", "Anna_200.txt", "Ben_50.txt", 
    "Ben_100.txt", "Ben_200.txt")

# get the numbers from the filenames
numbers <- vapply(strsplit(vapply(strsplit(files, "\\."), "[", i = 1, ""), "_"), "[", i = 2, "")

# only use those numbers that appear two times:
t.num <- table(numbers)
valid.num <- dimnames(t.num)[[1]][t.num == 2]

# make vector for Anna and Ben (that now have the same ordering)
f.anna <- paste("Anna_", valid.num, ".txt", sep = "")
f.ben <- paste("Ben_", valid.num, ".txt", sep = "")

#Now you can use mapply with a suitable function
# Did not check it as I dont have the files, but the logic should become clear:
run.fisher <- function(file1, file2) {
    d1 <- scan(file1)
    d2 <- scan(file2)
    d.matrix <- matrix(c(d1, d2), byrow = TRUE)
    fisher.test(d.matrix)
}

# now use mapply to obtain a list with all results:

mapply(run.fisher, f.anna, f.ben)
```

**UPDATE:** Actually you can reduce the line for obtaining the numbers from the filenames to:

```
files <- vapply(strsplit(files, "[\\._]"), "[", i = 2, "")
```